# weird behavior of package units or misunderstanding

Tags: r, units-of-measurement

I am using the package *units* and I am performing a simple operation and I am getting a wrong the result with units. Doing:

```
library(units)
H<-with(ud_units, ((1:10)*0.05)*m)
Q<-with(ud_units,1*m^3/s)
```

and I am getting

```
Q
>1 m^3/s

H
>Units: m
>[1] 0.05 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.25 0.30 0.35 0.40 0.45 0.50

H*Q
>Units: m^5/s
>[1] 0.05 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.25 0.30 0.35 0.40 0.45 0.50
```

Is it a bug?

On the other hand, with simple values the behavior is as expected

```
H<-with(ud_units, 0.5*m)
Q<-with(ud_units,1*m^3/s)
```

then

```
Q
>1 m^3/s
H
>0.5 m
H*Q
>0.5 m^4/s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release of version 0.4-4 package *units* fixed the result units bug when multiplying or dividing units vectors of different length.